# An apology to the Law Stack Exchange community

Tags: discussion, const-iption-trolling

I am the "const iption" troll. (The space is so this doesn't show as a Google hit for the word.) Const iption is, as you all know, something that I just made up; there is, in reality, no such legal process. I've been trolling about it because I thought it was funny; it wasn't. I've been wasting community resources, including others' valuable time. This was a mistake, and I promise not to do it again.

If there is any way I can help the community recover from the damage I've done, or to make up for the damage in other ways, please let me know.

Addressing concerns raised in comments, and other additional notes:

1. This was not intended to get more Google results for the word "const iption", but I definitely understand why other users would think that. I put a space in the uses of the word to avoid that.
2. I wasn't able to add spaces to the other posts, as they were either created by other users  or by unregistered sockpuppets I no longer have access to, and suggested edits are not available on Meta. Other users with sufficient reputation did it.
3. The word "const iption" was a combination of "constipation" and "conscription."
4. I circumvented account bans/deletions by creating more accounts (as you all know), and I circumvented IP bans with Tor.

Comment: Thank you for your honesty. See [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) for Stack Exchange's usual attitude towards problematic behaviour.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this Meta post is merely the latest in a long line of posts intended to get the word constiption onto google, rather than a genuine apology. I expect to see more apologies coming along shortly, each from different sockpuppet accounts

Comment: @Richard This is a real apology, and I'm not going to post more. I see why you thought that, though; I put spaces in the word so it won't show as a Google hit.

Comment: Go back and change all the others with this word. I tried but the system wont let me it says no suggested edits on Meta FSR

Comment: @Heddy I used a large number of sockpuppet accounts (basically one per post), and this is the only one I still have access to, so I can't edit other posts either. I would if I could, but I can't any more than you can.

Comment: I keep reading it as constipation. Was that part of the joke?

Comment: @ComicSansSeraphim Yes, it was.