# Should Tor users be blocked?

Tags: discussion

I recently tried signing up on law.stackexchange.com through [Tor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(network)) (to ask a question anonymously), and the signup page wouldn't let me, consistently giving the error:

> Something went wrong. Please contact us at community-support@stackoverflow.email for assistance.

Then I asked `community-support@stackoverflow.email` for help, and they basically said:

> Stop using Tor. We cannot help you. We cannot create the account for you manually, and we cannot remove the tor signup block.

That makes me wonder, does the community have an opinion on Tor users? Should Tor users be barred from participating on Law.SE?

Comment: You should ask this on https://meta.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 3):

### At least one person used Tor to troll us here

It's interesting to learn that Tor users are blocked now, especially after we had a user that [hounded us for about 2 weeks with senseless bovine excrement about a self-invented method of law that does not exist and led some of us into a spiral reaching out to make a smoke alert to draw volunteers from all stacks to burn and flag such posts.](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1546/why-are-my-const-iption-questions-unpopular/1549#1549) In their apology, [they said they used Tor to evade IP bans.](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1606/an-apology-to-the-law-stack-exchange-community)

As I learned in the process of trying to fight that troll, there are several users on other stacks that similarly used Tor to try and evade blocks at that time. Apparently, since October last year, Tor was put on the blocklist, possibly in part to fight such trolls.

Answer (score 0):

- Law.SE is for [*educational* purposes](/help/on-topic) only.
  Should you have serious concerns about maintaining anonymity, you are very likely seeking [specific legal advice](/q/221).
- That said since most countries restrict access to, surveil and censor the internet, using an anonymization network is a vital tool in recreating a *free* internet.
  Therefore I welcome the use of Tor, including as a contributor.
  This however is a *political* statement.
- Stack Exchange Inc. runs a business.
  Unfortunately various networks have been abused for interfering with business activities, so it is a management decision to secure profits.

Answer (score -1):

The site belongs to Stack Exchange. They have every right to set whatever rules on usage they like.

Feel free to set up your own site with your own rules.

Comment: The opinions of Stack Exchange Inc and the community sometimes differ (some famous examples include `Should Monica Cello be fired and publicly humiliated for requesting clarifications on upcoming policy?` and `should moderators be allowed to use AI detection tools?`), and while Stack Exchance Inc's opinion seems clear, I'm curious about the community's

Comment: @hanshenrik I speak neither for Stack Exchange nor the community. The above is my opinion.